# Is there a biblical basis for Satanists and/or Pagans giving sacrifice as depicted in pop culture and modern media?

Tags: biblical-basis, satan, sacrifice

I've read enough in the Bible to know that some **misguided Jews have given Yahweh both human and animal sacrifices.**

In fact I remember reading that one of the son's of Adam giving sacrifices and the other not giving animal sacrifices. God obviously preferred the one that make sacrifices.

But in modern days, most Christians don't know this and pop culture and media including movies, fictional books etc show Satanists as the one's doing sacrifices. This is believed to be true even by Chrisitians and also people who are not Chrisitians. Pop media has huge influence on peoples brains and if you ask most people they do say that Satan is the one asking for sacrifices. So, my question should be valid under biblical basis.

Now there are two possibilites:

1. First possibility which is less likely IMHO: The Bible depicts Satan as asking for sacrifices both human and animal. Maybe Satan accepting human sacrifices was introduced in the New Testament.
2. The second more likely possibility IMHO: As morals changed and sacrifices were frowned upon and during and after the rebranding of Christianity as a peaceful religion, fiction and pop media authors shifted the sacrifices part to Satan even though the Bible never mentions Satan asking for human sacrifice.

**So, here is the main question. Is there any actual biblical basis for Satanists and/or Pagans asking for human and animal sacrifices. Are there any biblical verses showing that Satan does ask for human sacrifice**

I need actual answers backed with Bible verses.

Also mentions of how and which pop fictions started the trend of Satan asking for human sacrifices would be appreciated, but not necessary.

Also, if you want to debate that God doesn't take human sacrifices, I'd like you to read all the verses. This is not up for debate and I don't want answers that conflict these verses:

(Joshua 7:15 NLT) (Wisdom 3:5-7 NAB) (1 Kings 13:1-2 NLT) (Leviticus 27:28-29 NAB) (Judges 11:29-40) (Deuteronomy 13:13-19 NLT) (Joshua 7:15 NLT) (Numbers 31:7- NLT) (Exodus 22:29-30)

Comment: Welcome to the site, and do read the Tour link at the bottom of this page for what this site is all about. Research is appreciated here, with links / sources to back your points up with. However, you have misunderstood the Bible re. your question, and the example you give. It was Cain who offered vegetable offerings to God, his brother Abel offering a lamb. Cain was so jealous of God's approval of Abel that he murdered his brother. Read Genesis 4:1-16. You may wish to adjust your comments accordingly.

Comment: Not enough for an answer, but: The Bible doesn't depict Satan asking for sacrifices. It depicts people sacrifing to idols (and also people sacrificing to God, but not human sacrifices). Satan barely even appears, and there is no claim that Satan is somehow behind the idols. The claim is all the other people are worshipping is man-made idols, not some other real supernatural being. Satan maybe tempts them to do this, but they are not literally worshipping Satan, the are worshipping some made-up deity.

Comment: @kutschkem I recommend reading the verses I posted in the edit. There are multiple verses mentioning human sacrifice in the bible and these were just the one's I found

Comment: I’m closing this question because it concerns what Satanists do and teach, not what Christians do and teach.

Comment: @curiousdannii Not even that, it asks about pop fiction regarding human sacrifice.

Comment: @curiousdannii I have modified my question to make the point clear. Please review it. **I want to know if there are bible verses saying that Satan asks for human & animal sacrifice. So, that does indeed come under Christianity and under the bible**

Comment: @ktsrwdb That is clearer, however we don't do verse search questions here, they're too subjective. If you haven't read it yet, please see [What types of questions can I ask on this site?](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3409/6071)

Comment: We don't allow "Is there a Biblical Basis for..." questions either as they're functionally identical to verse search questions. You need to demonstrate that some group of Christians teach some idea, then you can ask for the Biblical basis for that idea.

Comment: @curiousdannii Most Christians & even non-christians due to influence of pop media believe that Satan asks for human sacrifice. And I am asking if there is biblical basis for what these people believe.

Comment: @ktsrwdb If it's so common you should be able to demonstrate it. I don't think it's actual true, and don't know if I've ever heard the idea that Satan specifically asks for human sacrifice. Other religions certainly, but their connection to Satan is murky. So this is why it needs to be demonstrated - we need to see the precise doctrine that is being interrogated.

Comment: @curiousdannii pop media showing Satanists asking for human sacrifices. For example tons of movies showing this suffice as proof. And mind you, a lot of people believe what is shown in movies to be true. You know the truth because you are a mod in CHRS.SE. Most Christians don't read the bible whole. They only know the verses the pastor tells them and what they see on TV and what others tell them. There are even tons of user generated content/comments on the internet suggesting people believing that Satan asks for human sacrifices. Movies enough should be sufficient proof IMHO

Comment: We do have some questions asking for the origin of pop culture ideas, such as [this one](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/11468/6071). They're really not what this site is about however, and I'm not inclined to encourage more of them. This is Christianity.SE and we study the beliefs and practices of Christian groups, not Pop Culture. [Movies.SE] already exists if you want an explanation of them.

Comment: No, but the sacrifices of pagans are offered to demons, not to God, and I do not want you to be participants with demons. - 1 Corinthians 10:20

Answer (score 4):

I fear you have not read enough of the Bible because God hates human sacrifice. The pagan nations that surrounded the Israelites practiced human sacrifice as part of the worship of false gods. God declared that such “worship” was detestable to Him and that He hates it.

> You shall not worship the Lord your God in that way, for every abominable thing that the Lord hates they have done for their gods, for they even burn their sons and their daughters in the fire to their gods (Deuteronomy 12:31).

Furthermore, human sacrifice is associated in the Old Testament with evil practices such as sorcery and divination, which are also detestable to God:

> There shall not be found among you anyone who burns his son or his daughter as an offering, anyone who practices divination or tells fortunes or interprets omens, or a sorcerer (Deuteronomy 18:10).

Most Christians (those who read the Bible and live by God's standards) understand that there is no longer any need for the people of God to offer animal sacrifices because Christ Jesus instituted a new covenant.  Jesus quoted from the Old Testament when he said:

> I desire mercy, not sacrifice (Matthew 12:7).

To answer your main question, the Bible clearly shows that pagans offered human sacrifices to their false gods, and this was detestable to the Creator.

As to your request for information on "how and which pop fictions started the trend of Satan asking for human sacrifices" I will not dignify that with an answer.  Christianity Stack is about Christianity - not pop fiction.

Comment: There IS divinely condoned child sacrifice in the OT, like in Judges 11:39 in which Jephthah sacrifices his daughter after praying for a victory. He was not stopped at the last moment like Abraham. Josephus, the "go to" extrabiblical historical source for apologetics, wrote that Jephthah burned his daughter on Yahweh's altar, Also, arguably, mandated genocide, as in Deuteronomy 7:1-2, is a form of human sacrifice, as is Jesus' crucifixion in the NT (for He was made man).

Comment: god doesn't have a problem with sacrifices. He has a problem with sacrifices given to other gods. He wants people who pray to other gods killed and that includes sacrifices. He wants them for himself.

Comment: (Joshua 7:15 NLT) (Wisdom 3:5-7 NAB) (1 Kings 13:1-2 NLT) (Leviticus 27:28-29 NAB) (Judges 11:29-40) (Deuteronomy 13:13-19 NLT) (Joshua 7:15 NLT) (Numbers 31:7-18 NLT)

Comment: 20 “Whoever sacrifices to any god, other than the Lord alone, shall be devoted to destruction.[g]. Proving that the problem god has in the above verse you mentioned is sacrifice to other gods and not sacrifice itself.

Comment: Nothing in Judges suggests God approved of Jephthah's sacrifice, indeed it's quite a tragic story. The only time I can think of God actively pushing people towards human sacrifice is Abraham and Isaac, though he stopped it before the sacrifice happened. @ktsrwdb All of your comments however make it seem like you're here to prove a point, not learn what Christians believe and teach.

Comment: @curiousdannii I'm here to know if Satan asks for human sacrifice according to the bible. The point that god takes human sacrifices is not up for debate in the question as I have provided evidence by multiple verse. Not just one. There are many more verse I posted not just the one you mentioned.

Comment: @curiousdannii My question is clear. Does Satan ask for sacrifices both human and animal according to Christianity and the bible. Though I don't like god taking sacrifices and asking followers to kill people of other religions. That is not my question or point. The point I want to know if the bible says Satan asks for human sacrifice.